# In Symfony 2, how to redirect a URL to a Symfony bundle page?

Tags: php, symfony

I was trying to make a Symfony 2 page when accessed through a browser (ex. example.com) it will redirect to the index page of a bundle.

There shouldn't be a example.com/web or anything at all, how can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried?

Comment: Do you mean not-existing page, or a specific one?

Comment: I've tried it by editing a routing.yml file and writing the controller and its action. Nothing happens.

Comment: A specific page, it's already made, the name is just Index

Comment: I guess you want to remvoe "web"  from url path right? i.e. when you hit url www.example.com it should display your index page, if that is the case then  change your document root to include "web" e.g. if your documenr root is "/var/www/html then your updated document root will be /var/www/html/web this is applicable if you symfony project in /var/www/html

Comment: Yes I want to remove it. Oh I see, I'll try this thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can `redirect()` to generate an HTTP redirect.

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('bundle_index')); // 302 Moved
```

Or you render immediately without a redirect using `forward()`, so the URL wouldn't change.

```
return $this->forward($this->generateUrl('bundle_index'));
```

Comment: in what file should I include this?

Comment: In your home page controller action, you can include that single line. Have you rendered the home page successfully?

Answer (score 0):

The other option is to explicitly connect the home page path, to a controller.

```
# routing.yml
_default:
    resource: "@YourDefaultBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /
```